# How to determine why Win7 machine is crashing?

Tags: windows-7, crash, event-log

When my Windows 7 machine crashes, I can't find any information in the event logs that can help me track down the problem. Is there a setting I can turn on to log more information so I can capture the last action taken before the OS crashes?

I'm more interested in how to troubleshot these problems in general, rather than a specific solution to my current problem. Thanks.

Comment: More details on "crashes" please. What exactly happens?

Comment: The desktop crashes when I resume from sleep. Using the BSOD tool, it is a INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR bug where param1=0x9. But really I'm looking for the tools & steps to track down hardware failures and OS crashes.

Comment: You are going to need to learn how to use windbg...http://www.sevenforums.com/crash-lockup-debug-how/34871-advanced-principles-debugging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NirSoft provides two nifty tools to assess what went wrong with your machine
[BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to view BSOD dump files and
[AppCrashView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html)to view Application crash information

Or you could analyse the dump yourselfv
They live at `%SYSTEMROOT%\Minidump` using `WinDbg` or any other [Debugging tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx)